# How to build up a parameter server?

Tags: tensorflow

In distributed tensorflow, does a parameter server need to be built as a tensorflow server with both master service and worker service ? If the answer is yes, then can a ps machine also be a worker ?

Answer (score 1):

In distributed TensorFlow, every worker is also a master. Furthermore, TensorFlow runtime has only one kind of worker, unlike its predecessor DistBelief, which had specialized parameter server workers.

You implement traditional parameter server architecture by using some workers to store parameters and others to execute session.run requests.